# Given a ROM dump file, how do I reverse engineer it to determine the CPU it runs on?

Tags: reverse-engineering, instruction-set, rom

I recently bought a Sharp EL-9950 graphing calculator (which is considerably rare compared to the other brands). I have a copy of its OS upgrade file, which is essentially ROM dump for the new version (or at least I think it is).

I searched everywhere, but I couldn't find any info about the hardware of this calculator, and it was too expensive for me to try opening its case.

How do I go about reverse engineering the ROM dump (exactly 1MB) to determine at least which instruction set it uses (so I can format it with my own ROM someday, I guess?)

Thanks!

Comment: Consider asking reverse engineering questions on the [reverse engineering.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I tried to check if Stack Overflow has a specific reverse engineering sub-site, but it seems I didn't find it. Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IDA, RADARE 2 , binwalk ..., it may give you some useful information about the binary.